# Xcode Event only showing marker not name - TapKu?

Tags: iphone, xcode, calendar, tapku

I have just implemented the tapku library calendar into my app. The calendar displays a event list under the calendar. (cell view)

I have it so its shows a date using this code - @"2012-08-09 00:00:00 +0000".

How would i make it so that when the user click on the date above it shows a message like "Your birthday" in the cell below?

I used this to help me with the initial part - http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to replace "." with any string, you will have to edit the following method TKCalendarView.m:

```
 - (void) drawTileInRect:(CGRect)r day:(int)day mark:(BOOL)mark font:(UIFont*)f1 font2:(UIFont*)f2{

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",day];


r.size.height -= 2;
[str drawInRect: r
       withFont: f1
  lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
      alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];

if(mark){
    r.size.height = 10;
    r.origin.y += 18;
    // Editing done here .......
    [@"edit" drawInRect: r
            withFont: f2
       lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap 
           alignment: UITextAlignmentCenter];
}
```

}

Also if you want to enter longer string make sure to decrease the font size of label and other sizing properties of the label. Label here refers to (dot).